# Not able to access response from promise function into a variable which can be passed to another function

Tags: node.js, api, promise, axios, request

```
    function getToken()
    {
     return axios.request({
        url: "/xyz",
        method: "post",strong text
        baseURL: "https://api.testing.in/api/xyz",
        data: {    
        "ClientKey" : "xyz",
        "ClientSecret" : "xyz"
        }
      }).then(response => {
        // tokeniw=response.data.accessToken
        // console.log('Check data inside then :' + tokeniw)
        // return tokeniw;
        this.response = response.data
        return response.data.accessToken   
      })
    }
```

Here , i want to put response.data.accessToken into a variable outside this function

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the code and call it as:

```
function getToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.request({
            url: "/xyz",
            method: "post",
            baseURL: "https://api.testing.in/api/xyz",
            data: {
                "ClientKey": "xyz",
                "ClientSecret": "xyz"
            }
        })
            .then(response => resolve(response.data.accessToken))           
            .catch(e => reject(e))
    })
}


const token = await getToken();
```

Comment: Okay,but then how do i fetch this return value in a variable as whenever i try either it returns blank or promise object not response.data.accessToken

Comment: Please let me know if the edit helps